# How do I add my own data to a responsive US states map?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, responsive-design

The original script and example can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/)

I am attempting to replicate the example I linked to above, but with my own data for each US state.

The Javascript I am using is as follows:

```
<script>

    function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
        return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
            "<tr><td>Total payments</td><td>"+(d.total)+"</td></tr>"+
            "</table>";
    }

var payments_data ={}; [
    {"id": "MT","total": 12.00},
    {"id": "VT","total": 15.18},
    {"id": "AK","total": 62.55},
    {"id": "SD","total": 109.23},
    {"id": "ME","total": 145.21},
    {"id": "ND","total": 262.20},
    {"id": "NE","total": 413.00},
    {"id": "NH","total": 599.47},
    {"id": "LA","total": 717.04},
    {"id": "ID","total": 750.06},
    {"id": "NV","total": 764.34},
    {"id": "AL","total": 774.47},
    {"id": "WI","total": 789.23},
    {"id": "HI","total": 1075.21},
    {"id": "AR","total": 1227.37},
    {"id": "NM","total": 1701.42},
    {"id": "DC","total": 1809.02},
    {"id": "WY","total": 2250.30},
    {"id": "DE","total": 2494.48},
    {"id": "OR","total": 2542.89},
    {"id": "UT","total": 2780.83},
    {"id": "KS","total": 2946.89},
    {"id": "MD","total": 2954.24},
    {"id": "PR","total": 3138.22},
    {"id": "RI","total": 3187.63},
    {"id": "WV","total": 3837.98},
    {"id": "MS","total": 4858.46},
    {"id": "WA","total": 5171.90},
    {"id": "CO","total": 5333.45},
    {"id": "MN","total": 5678.03},
    {"id": "IA","total": 6839.82},
    {"id": "SC","total": 8565.94},
    {"id": "GA","total": 9190.85},
    {"id": "TN","total": 10585.28},
    {"id": "AZ","total": 11074.81},
    {"id": "MO","total": 12973.35},
    {"id": "KY","total": 13112.70},
    {"id": "OH","total": 14279.88},
    {"id": "CT","total": 14557.44},
    {"id": "IL","total": 15743.68},
    {"id": "VA","total": 21276.39},
    {"id": "OK","total": 21420.82},
    {"id": "IN","total": 24432.94},
    {"id": "MI","total": 28186.57},
    {"id": "NJ","total": 32415.05},
    {"id": "CA","total": 36112.53},
    {"id": "FL","total": 39197.80},
    {"id": "NC","total": 45638.26},
    {"id": "TX","total": 47788.73},
    {"id": "PA","total": 52278.45},
    {"id": "NY","total": 95690.33},
    {"id": "MA","total": 5062020.89} 
    ]

    .forEach(function(d){
        payments_data[d]={color:d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#147907")(d.total/100)};
        });

    /* draw states on id #statesvg */   
    uStates.draw("#statesvg", payments_data, tooltipHtml);
</script>
```

With that script the following two things occur:

1) My console log reports the following: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[d.id].color')"

2) The map's state polygons does not get colored

3) the 'toolTip' does not work

My best guess for the occurrence of #1 and #2 is that the .forEach loop isn't adding the color element to the data.

As for #3, I cannot explain why the toolTip is failing to materialize.

Comment: you cannot do `payments_data[d]` because `d` is an object.. what are you trying to do in the `forEach` ?

Comment: In the forEach, I am attempting to loop through each state record (or array) within the payments_data object, and add a 'color' element to the array that is a function of the totals element value of that array.

Comment: I think you'd want in your `forEach()` something like `this.color=d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#147907")(this.total/100);` so it creates that property on the current object in the iteration.  `payments_data[d]` is another form of `payments_data.d`, and in your case, `d` is an object and not a string/property name.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do what the original code does:

```
data.forEach(function(d){ 
        var low=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
            mid=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
            high=Math.round(100*Math.random());
        sampleData[d]={low:d3.min([low,mid,high]), high:d3.max([low,mid,high]), 
                avg:Math.round((low+mid+high)/3), color:d3.interpolate("#ffffcc", "#800026")(low/100)}; 
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want to generate random data, as the original code does, for the map. I already have data that I want to map, and would like to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

After 'cleaning up' (proper use of curly brackets, etc.) the payments_data variable, and re-writing the .foreach loop, I was able to successfully use my data for the map with the following:

```html
<script>

 function tooltipHtml(n, d){ /* function to create html content string in tooltip div. */
  return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
   "<tr><td>Total payments</td><td>"+(d.total)+"</td></tr>"+
   "</table>";
 }

var payments_data = [
    {id: "MT",total: 12.00},
    {id: "VT",total: 15.18},
    {id: "AK",total: 62.55},
    {id: "SD",total: 109.23},
    {id: "ME",total: 145.21},
    {id: "ND",total: 262.20},
    {id: "NE",total: 413.00},
    {id: "NH",total: 599.47},
    {id: "LS",total: 717.04},
    {id: "ID",total: 750.06},
    {id: "NV",total: 764.34},
    {id: "AL",total: 774.47},
    {id: "WI",total: 789.23},
    {id: "HI",total: 1075.21},
    {id: "AR",total: 1227.37},
    {id: "NM",total: 1701.42},
    {id: "DC",total: 1809.02},
    {id: "WY",total: 2250.30},
    {id: "DE",total: 2494.48},
    {id: "OR",total: 2542.89},
    {id: "UT",total: 2780.83},
    {id: "KS",total: 2946.89},
    {id: "MD",total: 2954.24},
    {id: "RI",total: 3187.63},
    {id: "WV",total: 3837.98},
    {id: "MS",total: 4858.46},
    {id: "WA",total: 5171.90},
    {id: "CO",total: 5333.45},
    {id: "MN",total: 5678.03},
    {id: "IA",total: 6839.82},
    {id: "SC",total: 8565.94},
    {id: "GA",total: 9190.85},
    {id: "TN",total: 10585.28},
    {id: "AZ",total: 11074.81},
    {id: "MO",total: 12973.35},
    {id: "KY",total: 13112.70},
    {id: "OH",total: 14279.88},
    {id: "CT",total: 14557.44},
    {id: "IL",total: 15743.68},
    {id: "VA",total: 21276.39},
    {id: "OK",total: 21420.82},
    {id: "IN",total: 24432.94},
    {id: "MI",total: 28186.57},
    {id: "NJ",total: 32415.05},
    {id: "CA",total: 36112.53},
    {id: "FL",total: 39197.80},
    {id: "NC",total: 45638.26},
    {id: "TX",total: 47788.73},
    {id: "PA",total: 52278.45},
    {id: "NY",total: 95690.33},
    {id: "MA",total: 5062020.89} 
    ];
     payments_data.forEach(function(d){
      var total = Math.round(d.total); 
      payments_data[d.id]={total:d.total,color:d3.interpolate("#e5f5f9", "#a7ddeb")(total/10000)};
      });
  
 /* draw states on id #statesvg */ 
 uStates.draw("#statesvg", payments_data, tooltipHtml);
</script>
```